# Accessing ASP textbox inside gridview for JS script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp:Gridview and I would like my JS script to trigger a modal when a cell is focused.
I have the following in my aspx file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewSLds" runat="server" CellPadding="0" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCreated="gridviewSLds_RowCreated">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-BorderWidth="0">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="item" HeaderText="Metric" SortExpression="item" ReadOnly="false" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox onfocusin="select()" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("item") %>'
                                            ID="txtfocus" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

My script is as follows:

```
            var usrfocustxt = document.getElementById('<%txtfocus.item%>');

        itemtypetxt.onfocus = function () {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }
```

But it tells me the name 'txtfocus' does not exist in the current context. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please remove the<%? Just like this var usrfocustxt = document.getElementById('txtfocus.item');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing several things wrong.
First of all if you want an ID in javascript you should use it like this:

```
var usrfocustxt = document.getElementById('<%= txtfocus.ClientID %>');
```

But this will still give you the error 'txtfocus' does not exist in the current context.

Because a GridView (and other Controls that repeat data), will give the TextBox a unique name and ID so it does not occur multiple times on a page. If you look at the HTML source you could have seen that the TextBox HTML code now looks something like this:

```
<input name="ctl00$mainContentPane$rptr$ctl05$txtfocus" id="mainContentPane_rptr_txtfocus_5" type="text">
```

The name and ID have been modified with a index number and other data to make it unique. 
So to find the correct TextBox it's much easier to call the modal popup function like this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfocus" runat="server" onfocus="focusTextBox(this.id)" class="modalpopup"></asp:TextBox>
```

Or you can bind the function to the TextBox with jQuery and a class name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.modalpopup').focus(function () {
            alert(this.id);
        });
    });
</script>
```